# Error about webscraping a youtube video: "NA' does not exist in current working directory"

Tags: r

I am doing an academic work and I´ve tried to use a code sent by my teacher, but it isn't working: it tells  'NA' does not exist in current working directory ('C:/Users/agnes/Documents').

I´ve put the paste in the same path to my R work directory.

```
library(abjutils)
library(tidytext)
library(reticulate)
reticulate :: use_python("users/agnes/anaconda3/python")
library(spacyr)
spacy_initialize("pt_core_news_sm")
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(stm)
library(tm)
library(ggridges)
library(formattable)
#library(subtools)
options(scipen = 999)
## Preparaando os comandos para baixar as legendas
#Campos bÃ¡sicos
fields_raw <- c("id", "title", "alt_title", "creator", "release_date",
                "timestamp", "upload_date", "duration", "view_count",
                "like_count", "dislike_count", "comment_count")
#Formatando os capos
fields <- fields_raw %>% 
  map_chr(~paste0("%(", ., ")s")) %>% 
  # usar &&& como separador de fields
  paste0(collapse = "&&&") %>% 
  # acrescentar aspas no inicio e no final do string
  paste0('"', ., '"') 
channel_url <- "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmZv19Iylu4"  

# montar query (comando) do youtube-dl
cmd_ytdl <- str_glue("youtube-dl -o {fields} -i -v -w --skip-download --write-auto-sub --sub-lang pt {channel_url}") 
view(cmd_ytdl)
# acrescentar diretorio
pasta_captions <- "C:/Users/agnes/Documents"  
fs::dir_create(pasta_captions) 
cmd <- str_glue("cd {pasta_captions} && {cmd_ytdl}") 
arquivos_captions <- dir(pasta_captions, pattern = '*.vtt', full.names = TRUE) 
amostra <- arquivos_captions[1] 
read_lines(amostra) [1:12]
```

Comment: this is because `arquivos_captions` object is empty with 0 characters.

Comment: Thanks! But what I can´t understand is why arquivos_captions object is empty if I had called youtubedl in order to download the video´s caption...